# Web Front end to execute shell script

Tags: shell, web

I am looking for simple solution (preferably Java, tomcat, etc...) to execute simple script on machine. Instead of giving some users access to OS level, they can just login on front end and execute the script from there. Also those scripts should have aliases. So user will need to know the alias to trigger some script on OS level without knowing the low level execution and logic.

BRs,

Comment: Sounds great.... so http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say 'simple' and '(preferably Java, tomcat, etc...)' just won't match ;-)

Apart from that: there are ajax based shell frontends out there, that is most flexible. You can use a reduced shell to limit access to certain commands.

But probably the easiest approach is to setup a few Alias configurations inside a plain http server pointing to cgi scripts. That's all you need. If you want to get some extra points you can add a primitiv front page (even a statical html page would do) to offer the commands available. Possibly with runtime arguments to chose from. And you might want to think about securing access using the simply authentication methods offered by the http server out of the box.